# injecting factory in controller angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem with angularJS factory and controller
i want to get the http reply in a factory and use the api reply in controller 
but i dont know how to handle the factory and inject it in controller

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http({ method: 'GET', url: "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1309320265504420965/posts?key=***************" }).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
      for (var i =0; i < data.items.length;i++)
      {

        var m,
        urls = [], 
        str = data.items[i].content,
        rex = /(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))/g;

        while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
          urls.push( m[1] );
          data.items[i].ImageURL = urls[0];
          } 
          //data.items[i].ImageURL = urls[0];
      }
      $scope.playlists = data.items;
  }).
  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or \\server returns response with an error status.
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for, but you can always return a promise by returning the http call. then grab that promise in controller and do something with it:

for example:
apiService.js

```
(function(app) {
    "use strict";

    app.factory("apiService", ["$http", function($http) {
        var get = function(url, config) {
            return $http.get(url, config);
        };

        var post = function(url, data, config) {
            return $http.post(url, data, config);
        };

        var put = function(url, data, config) {
            return $http.put(url, data, config);
        };

        var remove = function(url, config) {
            return $http.delete(url, config);
        };

        return {
            get: get,
            post: post,
            put: put,
            remove: remove
        };
    }]);
})(_app);
```

and in your controller just inject the service:

```
(function(app) {
    "use strict";

    app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "apiService", function($scope, apiService) {

            $scope.getData = function() {
                apiService.get("/server/data").success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).error(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            };
        }
    ]);
})(_app);
```

Optional (app.js):

```
var _app = _app || {};

(function() {

    "use strict";

    _app = angular.module("myApp", []);
})();
```

Comment: first thanks alot for ur fast response 
what do u mean by
$scope.getData = function() {
                apiService.get("/server/data").success(function(data)

Comment: that's just a demo of how you can create a generic service for all your external api call's. getData is just a sample function that shows how you can work with the promise that the apiService returns.